# routing between port vlan

Tags: debian, routing

I am new here. I will try my best to state my question clearly.

I am running a debian 10(R1) as a routing, and a vyos(R2). There's a layer 2 switch under the router. I have configured port VLAN: vlan2 p1,p3,p8, vlan3 p2,p4,p8. For vlan2 the subnet is 192.168.1.0/24 on R1, and for vlan3 the subnet is 192.168.2.0/24 on R2. I want to make something like this happen: 192.168.1.10 <----> 192.168.2.20. In order to make this happen I used added a 3rd interface(ens18) that is connected to p8 to R1, and assigned it with ip: 192.168.2.2.

I checked the dynamic routes, it has "192.168.2.0/24 via dev ens18 src 192.168.2.2"

I don't know what else should I do to make it happen.

Here's the topology I made with all I can.

[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIRgc.png)

I am using something called "Port Vlan",not 802.1q vlan. All I did was:

vlan1: 6

vlan2: 1,3,5

vlan3: 2,4,5

The reason I needed a switch with simple vlan function is that without vlan separating the broadcast domain, sometime devices connected with AP2 will be assigned with an ip provided from debian's dhcp server, instead of the expected, vyos' dhcp server.

Except for the question I am asking help with, everything else works fine, both router settings are working properly, devices acquires ip config from dhcp either router depending on with AP the device is connected.

Again, what I wanted to figure out is that for example, I want to be able to ssh to 192.168.2.1(vyos) through a device that is connected to AP1 with an ip "192.168.1.100", what do I need to make it happen? use ip route? ip rule? or iptables and how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do draw a topology. It needs to show your devices with IPs, the subnets, VLANs and the router interface IPs. The default gateway addresses you've configured for devices in your subnets are also important to know. You say that you've configured switch port 8 to be part of both VLAN 2 and VLAN 3 - is it a typo? If not, the interface has to be configured as a trunk port, and the device you're connecting there needs to support dot1q VLANs as well; generally trunk port is only used between network devices.

Comment: forgot - the routing tables would also be helpful.

Comment: I have edited this post again with a topology and with more explanation! Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the Debian automatically created a route that allows it to send traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.2.0/24. However TCP/IP is a two-way route and currently VYOS doesn't know how to send traffic back. So you need to add to the VYOS device a route telling it to send all traffic with destination address in 192.168.1.0/24 -net to 192.168.2.2.

Please note; this rule and the one Debian has created will allow the devices in VLAN 2 to reach devices in VLAN 3 and vice versa. This also means that all devices in both VLANs can reach the management interface of both routing devices.

Why devices in VLAN 2 might get an incorrecct IP address from the VYOS; I can't say, the setup is a bit overcomplicated. A separate management access to all network devices can be arranged in a simpler manner that guarantees that the devices can't get IPs in wrong ranges, can't reach each other through the wired network but have only internet access, and can't reach any of the network devices.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now I have another issue, I tried to ping 192.168.2.2 from vyos, and had no luck to get through. Seems like even 192.168.2.2 was also unknown to vyos.